# Can there exist a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{C}\backslash\{1/n:n\geq1\}\rightarrow\mathbb{H}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Can there exist a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{C}\backslash\{1/n:n\geq1\}\rightarrow\mathbb{H}=\{z:\Im(z)>0\}$? Here $f$ is not constant.

I tried to think about the function $\overline{f(\bar{z})}$ to get a contradiction, but found nothing.

Can you give me some tips? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g(z)=\frac  1 {f(z)+i}$. The $g$ is also analytic  on the same domain and it is bounded: $|g(z)| \leq 1$. Hence it has a removable singularity at the points $\frac 1 n$. It extends to a bounded entire function so it is  a constant by Liouville's Theorem. It follows that $f$ is itself  a constant.

Comment: It's a creative proof! Thanks!